# Can door contact switch turn on a light when open and send signal to fan when closed?

Tags: switch, light, fans

I have a small pantry in a new house which has been designed with insulated walls and doors, etc. with the idea being that it is kept at a different temperature to the rest of the house to store food. There is an air duct coming at the bottom to deliver fresh cool air and and inline fan and duct at the top of the unit to circulate the fresh air through the cupboard space. The fan should normally be in the off position but only comes on for 5 minutes after the doors have been closed.

I would like that when the door is opened, the interior light comes on and when placed back in the closed position the light is turned off and a signal is sent to the inline fan to turn it on. The inline fan has an overrun timer built in so I assume that as long as a signal was sent to the fan and the fan had a live feed that this would allow it to start up and then turn off automatically rather than the switch sending the live feed?

I would ideally like one type of door contact switch to make this all work but wonder if this would be possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 3):

#### Three Way Switch

Get a switch that is a **three-way switch**. The typical use is to have two switches activating the same circuit. In your case, you'll use it to switch between two parts of the same circuit. Hot to common. One connection that would normally be a traveler goes to the light and the other to the fan.

#### Two Pushbuttons - NO and NC

An alternative is two pushbutton switches side-by-side, both activated by opening the door. The fan switch would be normally open (NO), so it is closed when the door is closed and open when the door is open. The light switch would be normally closed (NC), so it is open when the door is closed and closed when the door is open.

In a quick search, I found three-way pushbutton switches either as "retro"/antique items (not sure why), as automobile components or as specialty items. Key things to look for, to make sure you don't have code issues:

- Voltage rating - Make sure it is rated for your usage - typically 120V (US/Canada) or 240V (elsewhere)
- Current rating - Ordinary switches are rated for 15A or 20A to match the circuits. Some of the pushbutton switches I found were rated much lower - 10A or even 3A. While more than enough for a fan or LED lights, *usually* switches are supposed to be rated the same as the circuit they serve. If you can't find a 15A-rated switch then you should look into the code issues to make sure you don't have a real problem.
- Listing - Line voltage switches (US - other places vary) are normally UL or ETL *listed*. This is an important assurance of quality and if you don't have properly listed switches and have a fire then you may have a *big* problem.

Comment: IIUC, you're suggesting that the OP put a standard 3-way switch in his pantry so that he can flip the switch up for the lights and down for the vent fan (or vice-versa). However, the OP seems to want an automatic switch that turns the lights on when the door opens and the lights off/fan on when it closes. Am I misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: I am suggesting a **pushbutton** 3-way switch lined up with the pantry door so that opening the door unpushes the button and closing the door pushes the button. Come to think of it, that's more of a "momentary" (while pushed down) switch - it may be that the pushbutton switches I've found so far are more like "push to toggle", but I haven't checked enough details. In theory what I am describing should be easy enough, but the devil is in the details...

Comment: Good to hear! Based on my reading, I wasn't certain and wanted to clarify.

Comment: Ideally you'd want a single switch/push-button that has BOTH normally-open and normally-closed connections.  No idea where to find such a thing though.

Comment: @IceGlasses Which would be the same (functionally) as a 3-way switch.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact True; I guess I've only heard "3-way" used to describe light switches, while relays or sensors (stuff with more defined on/off states I suppose) use NO/NC terminology.

Comment: A switch is a switch, of course, of course. When I was a kid, we had a 3-way switch installed to alternate between two dishwashers. I didn't realize at the time how it worked, but now I understand. (The switch was to prevent the dishwashers running at the same time because of plumbing limitations - running a separate circuit to have enough electricity to run both dishwashers at the same would have been easy.) (And on the other hand, we had a timer in the dining room that was *not* designed for 3-way switches  so the other switch was always "don't touch this". If we had DIY SE in the 1970s...)

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Reminds me of when the dining room chandelier in an older (~1920s) house wouldn't come on. We ended up calling an electrician, who found another (3-way) switch in the circuit, in a hard-to-see corner of the room, whose toggle had been pushed into its center no-contact position. D'oh.

Comment: The problem I have with the fan coming on when the doors are open is that it kind of defeats the purpose because it will draw warm air in from the kitchen when the doors are opened which would also cause a draft.

I had a chat about this with an electrician last night and he is currently looking at a the following type of relay: https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/latc...6E6669673D3026&searchHistory={"enabled":true}
Have any of you had any experience with this relay and is it something that you think would work in this instance?

Comment: If you read carefully, @BrianMcDermott, I believe this suggests doing exactly what you're after. The only thing it doesn't include is a timer to turn the fan off after 5 minutes, or whatever, but maybe that's already handled by the fan itself.

Comment: @FreeMan Correct. Both a 3-way switch and dual switches (one NO, one NC) would make "light on only when doors open" + "fan on only when doors closed" and that combines with OP's statement of "The inline fan has an overrun timer built in" to take care of the 5-minute timing. If the fan doesn't have that then a separate timer would need to be added.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the light and fan are both powered by 120V outlets there is an easy way to do this, based on a "NCNO" reed switch and a couple of relays.  This minimizes the 120V cabling and switching that needs to be mounted directly in the door frame.

Install a switch like this on your door:
[image]

The magnet is mounted on the door, the switch on the frame.  The switch has three contacts so one circuit is closed when the door is open and a different circuit is closed when the door is closed.

Each of those circuits will be used to control the low voltage side of a relay that will power your light and fan.

A good relay is the [CLC212 from Functional Devices](https://www.functionaldevices.com/products/lighting-controls/light-controllers/) (assuming your fan uses more than 5 amps, otherwise the CLC106 will suffice).   These relays are designed for closets, they install in a junction box where they connect to the 120V-side to power things, and they properly separate the low volt wires to the reed switch through a knockout in the box.   You'll need two of them, one for the light and one for the fan.   The light one can control a ceiling light or you can install an outlet inside the closet, switched by the relay, that will power the PSU for LED strip lighting that you can stick on to the back of the closet doorframe.

[image]

If you use these relays, you would use two of them, discard the reed switches that come with them, and use a three-way reed switch instead.

A nice thing about these three-way reed switches is that if you choose relays that expect normally-closed (like for security applications) or normally-open (like for lighting) you can easily get it right simply by reversing the connections to the switch.

If you're going to do all this I recommend you use a deep 4-gang box for two relays, one switched outlet (maybe split) and another unswitched outlet for whatever future needs (Chargers etc).  The relay and all its wiring get pretty crowded in a 1-gang space.

**Edit** (in response to comment, and to emphasize the need for separation): Here are a couple of pics of the relay in finished state.  In the first one the switch wire comes out a bottom knockout and both sockets are switched.  In the second one, the relay is in a separate box connected with an RMC nipple, switch wires exit a top knockout, and in the outlet box one socket is separated for the lights, the other three are for other things including a router you can see.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I see where the RiB is listed (per NEC 110.2) however it must also be installed per instructions (per NEC 110.3) which the relay going through a knockout hole. That's so the low-voltage is outside the box, and the mains is inside, and you have separation. The above photo seems to have it crudely stuffed inside a box, where LV is intermingling with mains. Easy to fix in the pictured installation since it's surface mount, and proper placement  would also allow fitting of a proper domed cover. No more cover plates snagging clothes!

Comment: It's installed properly.   The relay is correctly mounted in a knockout.   The grey plastic flap is L-shaped.  Part of it, not seen, is the retaining clip for the relay in the knockout.  The LV wire (seen) comes out that way, and I've wrapped the excess around the flap.  The part that you do see is intended for when the junction box is in a finished wall cavity, and a hole is made next to it for the LV wire to enter the closet space. The grey plastic flap blocks that hole a little from the back of the wallboard.   I think I have a pic of the finished covered thing in another post.

Comment: I added a couple of pics showing completed relay in use.

Comment: OK so you're saying your RiB has the *low voltage* wires coming through the knockout thread? Oh, that's fine then. That differs from the relay you linked, hence my confusion.

Comment: Ah!  I didn't notice ... You are correct.  Mine are the 5A CL106 that mounts inside the box, and the LV wires exit directly through the knockout.   I did not notice that the 10A version I linked is the opposite, with the relay outside and the HV wires inside the knockout.    I suggested the 10A one on the baseless assumption that the fan needs more than 5A.

Comment: So!  Actually, my recommendation of a 4 gang box is unnecessary if the fan relay is in fact the bigger model and it is outside the box.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica thanks for the buyer's remorse :) Now I see the 10A one is half the price of the 5A one and in the second example I would not have needed the second box.   Waa!

Comment: Well if you ever need a 10, buy a 5 and swap :) What's notable in this conversation is that a surface-mount (presumably steel, as they have knockouts) junction box would be needed somewhere suitable, to mount the RIB.